# Certification Authority migration - cannot install Web Enrollment role

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, certificate, migration, pki, windows-server-2003

I used [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126140%28WS.10%29.aspx) to migrate a certificate authority `my root CA` from a Win2003 AD server `oldserver` to a Win2008R2 member server `newserver` (with different name). After completing this task, I wanted to install the web enrollment role service on `newserver`, but that fails with (translated from German)

> The certification authority web enrollment cannot be installed.
>
> Active Directory Certificate services setup failed with the following error code: The parameter is incorrect. 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87)

I verified that `oldserver` does not appear anywhere under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\CertServ`

In server manager under `AD Certificate Services/Enterprise PKI/my root CA` all entries are either http with `newserver` or ldap with `my root CA` instead of a specific server name.

In Active Directory Sites and Services, under `Services/Public Key Services/AIA/` there `newserver$` has full access on `my root CA`. Under `Services/Public Key Services/CDP/` there are folders `oldserver`and `newserver`and each contains `my root CA` and `my root CA(1)` and `my root CA(3)`. For all of these, `newserver$` has full access rights.

All this looks to me as if I had done everything right - so what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a consequence of exactly following the procedure suggested by Microsoft:

- They suggest to first install *only* the CA without additional role services
- They suggest to edit the registry settings exoported/imported only regarding server names

As a consequence, I did *not* directly install the Web Enrollment. However, as [I meanwhile found out](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12035.ad-certification-authority-web-enrollment-configuration-failed-0x80070057-win32-87.aspx), the registry contains a setting that states that Web Enrollment is already installed. Changing the setupstatus from 0x6003 to 0x6001 as suggested solved the problem.